# change the background of an id that is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

When one of the element(id) of a form is clicked, i would like to listen to that event, and change the background of that element.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('click', function(e){        
        var x = e.target.id;
        $(x).css('background-color',color);
        return false;
    });
}


<form>
  <div id="a">Item1</div>
  <div id="b">Item2</div>
  <div id="c">Item3</div>
</form>
```

Comment: you could use `$(this)`

Comment: You do know `$(this)` always references the element that triggered the event handler right?

Comment: for your existing code to work, shouldn't you use  `$("#"+x)`.?

Comment: I guess `e.target` because he can then put in any elements within the form, and it still will work, without changing the selectors every time he adds something in. OP - `e.target` is already a node - as such there's no need to search for it - just do `$(e.target).css('background-color', color)`

Comment: @eithedog That's why `on` (http://api.jquery.com/on/) allows usage of selectors for it's second parameter in order to fine tune the selection of elements on which the event handler will be triggered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will end up looking for tag names because the selector is

```
$("b")
```

If you want to do it the way you have it, you would need to add the missing `#`.

```
$("#" + x).css('background-color',color);
```

But there is no need to look up the element when you already have a reference to is. Use event delegation and this

```
$('form').on('click', 'div', function(e){        
    $(this).css('background-color',color);
});
```

Comment: I actually vote this the best solution because of the explicit narrowing of the results through the second parameter of `on`.

Answer (score 1):

Why bother using `e.target`? Just update your code to use `$(this)`:

```
$(function() {  
    $('form > div').on('click', function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css('backgroundColor', color);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work out. Take care of your tags.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on('click', function(e){   
        var x = e.target.id;
        $("#"+x).css('background-color',"red");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing happening to you is that event.target.id returns a string representing the id of the element, not a selector. So where you use $(x).... you have to use $('#'+x), your actual code does not work because the selector for the background change is not looking for an element with the X value on the Id but for an element called like the value of X (eg. x="a", then it's looking for  elements)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my "lowly" try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = 'es'>
    <head>
        <title> My Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
          <div id="a"> Item1 </div>
          <div id="b"> Item2 </div>
          <div id="c"> Item3 </div>
        </form>
        <script>
            function addBackgroundColor(e){
                var index = parseInt(Math.random() * 4); // the number of the multiplier has to be equal to the length of the array colorsList.
                e.target.style.backgroundColor = colorsList[index];
            }

            var colorsList = ['blue','red','green','yellow','orange']; //add others colors here if you want.
            var divsList = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
            for (var i in divsList){
                divsList[i].addEventListener('click', addBackgroundColor);
            }   

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to go fancy. Just do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form div').on('click', function(e){        
        $(this).css('background-color',color);
        return false;
    });
}
```